# Write a data frame to a .xls file with a title

Tags: r, xlsx, dunn.test

I adapted a [script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27557635/1354580) to run the multiple (post-hoc) comparisons `dunn.test` function from the `dunn.test` package, on multiple variables, which generates multiple data frames, saved with the bellow (simplified) code in an .xls file as separate tables. What I want is to save with the each date frame also the name of variable (column) that was analyzed, **as table titles** (not column titles). I am looking for a solution for several hours, but without success. How to do this? They are too many and I do not want to enter them manually.

```
wb <- createWorkbook()
sheet <- createSheet(wb, sheetName="Sheet1")
# start analyzing data in a for loop here
# and add created data frames to a sheet
    addDataFrame(mydataframe, sheet)
# end loop here
saveWorkbook(wb, "myfile.xls", sep="")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could convert your source data.frame to a text matrix, prefix whatever title you want, and write that to file.

For example, given this data.frame:

```
dat <- data.frame(Fruit=c('Apple', 'Banana'), 
                  Quantity=1:2, 
                  Notes=c('Hello', 'Some Text'))
```

You could use a function like this:

```
text_matrix <- function(dat, table_title) {

  rbind(c(table_title, rep('', ncol(dat)-1)), # title
        rep('', ncol(dat)), # blank spacer row
        names(dat), # column names
        unname(sapply(dat, as.character))) # data

}
```

Then you can call the function and write the output to file (using write.table or one of the xls conversion packages if you must).

```
temp <- text_matrix(dat, table_title='Here is a table title')
write.table(temp, 'temp.csv', row.names=F, col.names=F, sep=',')
```

The result, opened in Excel, is this:

[image]

Comment: Excellent! Excepting that numeric values now are recognized by LibreOffice Calc (maybe also by Excel) only as a text and this is not good.

Comment: You could add `quote=FALSE` to the write.table command, and the numbers should turn back to numbers in the spreadsheet. If you know none of the strings in your data need to be enclosed in quotes (the way string containing commas do, e.g.), that will be the easiest fix

Comment: By the way, can be done this  with the `write.xlsx` directly in a .xls file?

Answer (score 0):

Hope the following helps. I created quickly an example dataset. Output.csv can be found in your home directory. Opening it in excell will show the column titles.

```
n = 20
set.seed(12345)
data = data.frame(cbind(pond=1:2, habitat=1:3, value = rnorm(n)))

write.csv(data, file="output.csv")
```

Comment: `Warning message: In cbind(pond = 1:2, habitat = 1:3, value = rnorm(n)) : number of rows of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 2)`. But where is the title?

Comment: the titles pond, habitat, value open in your spreadsheet if you open the .csv file with excel

Comment: O, I see! But, it seems I was not very explicit. I want a title for the saved table (data frame), not for columns.